# How to use the knobs and sliders in the special functions menu of the TX16s Mk4?

Tags: transmitter, edgetx, tx16

I'd like to set up a volume control, and there are several [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVmX5YbxjXw) showing how to do it. They all go to the Special Functions menu, pick a knob or slider and set the function to Volume. I had this working fine on my old radio, but on my new one (I think it's a Mk4, running EdgeTx) the knobs and sliders aren't listed, just the switches.

In all the videos I've seen, switches A to H are followed by S1 and S2 for the knobs and then the sliders.

Any idea what's going on?

[image: transmitter screen]